# Apache HTTP Server is running without no executable! How is this possible?

Tags: linux, httpd

When I logged in to an EC2 instance created by someone else to host Apache HTTP Server I cannot run
any of common Apache commands but the Apache is running:

```
$ ps -aux | grep apache
jimble   22250  0.0  0.0  12944   864 pts/0    S+   02:28   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

How is this possible? Where is the Apache executable?

```
$ apache2
The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install apache2-bin

$ httpd
No command 'httpd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'http' from package 'httpie' (universe)
 Command 'xttpd' from package 'xtide' (universe)
httpd: command not found

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: apache on this machine is neither running, nor installed. Install it and try again.

Answer (score 2):

That's not apache. That's grep - the very grep you ran there. This is why pgrep exists.

Comment: is correct apache is not running on your server but if you still want to check the status then run this command : systemctl status apache2